# How to find the minimum $m$ for a given $n$ in this inequality?

Tags: calculus, inequality

For a given $n \in \Bbb N$, how do you find the minimum $m \in \Bbb N$ which satisfies the inequality below?

$$3^{3^{3^{3^{\unicode{x22F0}^{3}}}}} (m \text{ times}) > 9^{9^{9^{9^{\unicode{x22F0}^{9}}}}} (n \text{ times})$$

What I have tried to do so far is decomposing the $9$ on the right side to $3*3$
or to $3^2$, but both ways didn't get me much far and I couldn't find a pattern.

Comment: Do you mean, find the minimum $m$ as a function of $n$?

Comment: I'm really confused.  Are you asking to find, given $n \in \Bbb N$, the smallest $m \in \Bbb N$ such that $3^{3^{3^{3m}}} > 9^{9^{9^{9n}}}$?

Comment: no, i tried to made it more clear in my edit, but the left side is 3^3^3^3^3^3.. and so on m times, is it clear now?

Comment: Why don't you start by writing down the values of $m$ for $n=1,2,3$, so you can see a pattern (if such one exists)? Add the results here, so we can appreciate your effort in trying to solve this problem a little more than we are appreciating it at present (and in addition to that, we can search for a pattern ourselves).

Comment: BTW, there's a way to make those dots "go up diagonally".

Comment: @DanielKatzan I edited your question.  Please review it to make sure I did not make any mistakes in interpreting what you are asking.  Also, for the future, when you write $\text{3^...}$, only the first . is raised as an exponent, which is why your math looked weird.  If you want to raise all three dots, you could write $\text{3^{...}}$ or $\text{3^{\dots}}$.

Comment: For the record to anyone that is interested, apparently on StackExchange you can use $\unicode{x22F0}$ by writing, for example, $\text{3^{\unicode{x22F0}}}$ between dollar signs to get $3^{\unicode{x22F0}}$.

Comment: Intuitively, power towers depend primarily on the number of levels and much less on the numbers used.  I would expect that $m=n+1$.  It is certainly true for $n=1,2$ and already at $n=2 the tower of $9$'s is minuscule by comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$9^{9^{9^{9^{\dots}}}} n$ times $= 3^{2*3^{2*3^{2*3^2{\dots}}}} $, where the upper most $2$ is $(n+1)^{th}$ power.

$2*3^2 < 3^{2+1} = 3^3 $

$\implies 9^{9^{9^{9^{\dots}}}} n$ times $\lt 3^{3^{3^{3^{\dots}}}} n+1 $ times

So, $ m = n + 1 $

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you with certainty that `m+n+1` is the minimum value for m. Working it out is the real problem. I'm sure it's correct, though, because if you take the 3's n+1 times and subtract the 9's n times,

```
3^3^3^3 (n+1 times) - 9^9^9 (n times) > 0
```

it's always positive and the difference is increasing. I have not, however, been able to model this with a function that you can take the derivative of and find a minimum value for.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_1=3,b_1=9,a_{n+1}=3^{a_n},b_{n+1}=9^{b_n}$ obviously we have $a_n ,b_n \in N$

$a_1<b_1$ .Suppose $a_n<b_n$ then

$$a_{n+1}=3^{a_n}<3^{b_n}<9^{b_n}=b_{n+1}$$

$a_2>2b_1$ Suppose $a_n>2b_{n-1}$ then

$$a_{n+1}=3^{a_n}\ge3^{2b_{n-1}+1}=3\cdot 9^{b_{n-1}}=3b_n>2b_n$$

Thus by induction $a_n<b_n<\dfrac {a_{n+1}} 2<a_{n+1}$ hence the result follows